# Resource is out of sync error when opening project.properties files

Tags: android, eclipse

I get the following error whenever i try to open the project.properties file of my project :- **Could not open the editor: Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/FamilyTracker/project.properties'.**

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is this in eclipse? Is the file opened somewhere else? Try to click on "Refresh" after selecting the file.

In eclipse, you can enable auto-refresh on Window->Preferences menu, then General > Workspace.
There, mark  “Refresh automatically”. This will take care of refreshing the files for you automatically and avoid out of sync messages even if you are editing the file outside of eclipse as well.

By the way, on the Indigo version of Eclipse, the automatic refresh setting is now as "Refresh on access"

Comment: Okay. Thanks, actually i'm trying to add SherlockActionBar library to my project. I imported the library as a separate project but when i try to add it in my current project as a library it fails. I went through all the possible reasons over the internet but of no use.

Answer (score 0):

select project name and Right Click--> Refresh, then do your changes like renaming project name or related things.

Answer (score 0):

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace

[image]