# Project description file(.project) is out of sync with the file system

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-juno

Every project which I import to eclipse 1st give me this error [image]
Then if I click ok, then library issues comes in which always it adds a broken library with a cross(X) mark. I tried many ways to fix this, This problem can be solved by fixing the error shown in the screenshot.

Anyone knows why its causing the error?

Help!!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, `refresh` is not working, i try remove the project from eclipse workspace then import it again, finally it work.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what is happening, is that you change things externally which Eclispse cannot keep track of, hence I am guessing your `.project` file was moved.

A way to solve this is to refresh your project folder, `Project > Refresh`. For more [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343735/avoiding-resource-is-out-of-sync-with-the-filesystem)

Or try the `refresh using native hooks or polling method` which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545544/resource-is-out-of-sync-error-when-opening-project-properties-files)

If worst comes to worst I would suggest recreating your project file and copying all the files over to the new project.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

first go ahead and refresh your project so eclipse would re-sync any external changes to the file system, then to avoid facing this again because you probably will!  go to `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace`
Now check:

```
Refresh Automatically
```

or

```
Refresh using native hooks or pooling
```

one more thing try to give up on eclipse and download android studio, it is much much better.